# Results Positioning CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the position of my mysql database results using HTML and CSS.

All of the hi's that you see on the page are supposed to be under the column "Good Comment"

All of the asasd and BAD (4 in total) are supposed to be under the right column "Bad Comment"

This doesn't seem to work for some reason.

The following is my css.

```
.leftSide {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 500px;
}

.goodComments {
display: inline-block;
width: 500px;
}

.rightSide {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 300px;
}

.badComments {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 500px;
width: 300px;
}
```

PHP:

```
function fetchBad() {

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=ProCons", $username, $password);
/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/

/*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ConSubmissions";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) { 
    echo $row['Comments'] .' - '. $row['TimeStamp'] . '<br />';
}
/*** close the database connection ***/
$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: At first glance, your goodcomments and badcomments arent even inside the left side and right side divs you have set up?

Comment: MySQL/PHP is unrelated to the final application of HTML/CSS (they may be used as a *source* to generate the resources, but are otherwise inconsequential)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I went ahead and looked at your page. I think you need to restructure your HTML to be a little bit cleaner. I'll show you what I came up with below.

Your styles can be simplified to something like this.

```css
.leftSide {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 500px;
}

.rightSide {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 300px;
}

.goodComments {
    color: #457356;
}

.badComments {
    color: #912727;
}
```

And as far as your HTML, I would actually put your comments into their respective sides, for example like this.

```html
...
<div class="leftSide">
    <form action="./index_files/index.html" method="POST">
        Good Comment: <input type="text" name="GoodComment" id="GoodComment" maxlength="140">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <div class="goodComments">hi - 2014-03-14 15:42:21</div>
    <div class="goodComments">hi - 2014-03-14 15:42:19</div>
</div>

<div class="rightSide">
    <form action="./index_files/index.html" method="POST">
        Bad Comment: <input type="text" name="BadComment" id="BadComment" maxlength="140">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <div class="badComments">adfad - 2014-03-14 16:20:20</div>
    <div class="badComments">asdff - 2014-03-14 16:20:21</div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

style.css:

```
.comment{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php
function fetchBad() {

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=ProCons", $username, $password);
/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/

/*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ConSubmissions";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) { 
echo $row['Comments'] .' - '. $row['TimeStamp'] . '<br />';
}
/*** close the database connection ***/
$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>

<div class="comment">
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
Good Comment: <input type="text" name="GoodComment" maxlength="140">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
fetchGood()
?>
</div>

<div class="comment">
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
Bad Comment: <input type="text" name="BadComment" maxlength="140">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
fetchBad()
?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm adding comments through my mysql query like             echo "<div class='goodComments'>" . $row['Comments'] .' - '. $row['Timestamp'] . "<br /></div>";

Comment: That does not work. I have a function running my php. Do you have a skype?

Comment: I added the php for one of the functions.

Comment: Should my css only have the .comments?

Comment: I get the following error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/content/35/11314435/html/client/index.php on line 19

Comment: Try it now, it should be fixed using your functiob